# renaming column in jqGrid which is in MMYYYY format

Tags: c#, jqgrid

I want to rename my column in jqGrid which is currently in this format MMYYYY
i want something like this Jan 2018, Feb 2018 and so on.
the columns MMYYYY are dynamically generated at runtime. It is generated based on From and To Dates.

so, i want this to be done in C# code.
thanks!

Comment: Do it in the UI and send an ISO8601 date string. Trust me, it makes more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i achieved it :

```
var  dateFor = i.ToString("MMyyyy");
                    dateFor= GeneralFunction.GetMonthName((dateFor.Substring(0, 2).Trim()))+" "+dateFor.Substring(2,4).Trim();

public static string GetMonthName(String monthNum)
    {
        string MonthName = "";

        switch (monthNum)
        {
            case "01":
                MonthName = "Jan";
                break;
            case "02":
                MonthName = "Feb";
                break;
            case "03":
                MonthName = "Mar";
                break;
            case "04":
                MonthName = "Apr";
                break;
            case "05":
                MonthName = "May";
                break;
            case "06":
                MonthName = "Jun";
                break;
            case "07":
                MonthName = "Jul";
                break;
            case "08":
                MonthName = "Aug";
                break;
            case "09":
                MonthName = "Sep";
                break;
            case "10":
                MonthName = "Oct";
                break;
            case "11":
                MonthName = "Nov";
                break;
            case "12":
                MonthName = "Dec";
                break;

        }

        return MonthName;
    }
```

thank you everyone. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the label property to set the label of the column

```
{ 
    "label": "Jan 2018", 
    "name": "firstmonth", 
    "width":"150",
}
```

or just use the method setLabel to change the grid header label

```
....
$("#grid").jqGrid("setLabel", "firstmonth", "Jan 2018");
...
```

after the grid is created